# Why does bash send SIGTERM to program after logout despite setting nohup and disown

Tags: background-process, signals, nohup, sigterm

I want to run a program which continues after logout from an ssh session.

I've tried:

```
nohup myProg > /tmp/logfile 2>&1 &
disown %1
```

and

```
systemd-run --scope --user myProg -p > /tmp/logfile 2>&1  &
```

In both cases, the process receives a SIGTERM from the bash process which launched it.

(The program uses `sigaction` for signal handling, which identifies the PID that sent the signal)

```
struct sigaction sigActionInfo;
sigActionInfo.sa_sigaction = DvsRebuildInfoFiles::signalHandler;
sigActionInfo.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigemptyset(&sigActionInfo.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGINT,  &sigActionInfo, 0);
sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigActionInfo, 0);
```

and

```
DvsRebuildInfoFiles::signalHandler(int sigNo, siginfo_t *sigInfo, void *context)
{
    pid_t sendingPid = sigInfo->si_pid;
    printf("DvsRebuildInfoFiles: Received Signal %d from process %d\n", sigNo, sendingPid);
}
```

Watching the log file from another terminal session confirms that it is `bash` which sends `SIGTERM`.

```
# ps -lf
F S UID          PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S root      858355  858354  0  80   0 - 59839 -      03:40 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
0 S root      858530  858355 12  80   0 - 944937 -     03:40 pts/0    00:00:01 ./DvsRebuildInfoFiles -p
0 S root      858906  858530  0  80   0 - 55622 -      03:40 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c /usr/local/dvstor/bin64/DvGetProgramList /mnt/das.a/202307
0 D root      858907  858906  0  99  19 - 35888 -      03:40 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/local/dvstor/bin64/DvGetProgramList /mnt/das.a/20230719.085
etc. etc.
```

Why does it do that and can it be prevented?

**NOTES**

1. I don't know if this is relevant but the program itself launches
   many threads, each thread in turn executes another program via
   `system()`.
2. Recoding the signal handler is not an option because the program
   must be able to be stopped with a signal.
3. `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` has the line commented out
4. Access is via ssh. No GUI.